# Error in Page Load: The schema for field with this name is wrong or missing . field 'IconOverlay'

Tags: 2013, error, page-load

I received the below error while loading the page.

> The schema for field with this id is wrong or missing.  field
>   '{7d95d1f4-f5fd-4a70-90cd-b35abc9b5bc8}'.
>
> The schema for field with this name is wrong or missing .  field
>   'IconOverlay'.

If any body come across this issue, please share your thoughts..

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error. My issue turned out to be a mismatch in my field names used in the page (and visible from SharePoint Designer). I had an uppercase D when it should have been lowercase (or they just all should have matched).

Here's a snippet of what I had:

```
<td width="70%" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Explanation_x0020_of_x0020_data_" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Explanation_x0020_of_x0020_Data_')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="Explanation_x0020_of_x0020_data_" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
```

The second @Explanation_x0020_of_x0020_Data_ did not match the first and third instances of @Explanation_x0020_of_x0020_data_

Once I made them match, things worked.